# Javascript allow comma and numeric for currency money textbox

Tags: javascript, regex, currency

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#Salary").keyup(function (e) {
            var isFloatNumber = IsFloatOnly('input#Salary');
            if (!isFloatNumber) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("#ErrorMessage").text('Invalid value. Please enter numeric value.');
            }
            else {
                $("#ErrorMessage").text('Success.');
            }
        });
    });

    function IsFloatOnly(element) {
        var value = $(element).val();
        var regExp = "^\\d+(\\,\\d+)?$";
        return value.match(regExp);
    }
</script>
```

**Html:**

```
<input type="Text" id="Salary" maxlength="20" name="Salary" />
<label id="ErrorMessage"></label>
```

**Question:**

If i write value as below,

```
100,00
```

100,00 is okay.Message displays **Success**

However

If i write value as below,

```
1,000,05

10,000,00
```

Error message displays **Invalid value**.

How can i allow also **1,000,05** and **10,000,00** values to be success according to my regex in javascript ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regexp only allows one comma. The `?` quantifier means zero or one of the preceding element. If you want to allow any number of them, use `*`.

```
var regExp = /^\d+(,\d+)*$/;
```

Also, use a RegExp literal so you don't have to escape the backslashes. And there's no need to escape comma in a regexp.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#Salary").keyup(function(e) {
    var isFloatNumber = IsFloatOnly('input#Salary');
    if (!isFloatNumber) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#ErrorMessage").text('Invalid value. Please enter numeric value.');
    } else {
      $("#ErrorMessage").text('Success.');
    }
  });
});

function IsFloatOnly(element) {
  var value = $(element).val();
  var regExp = /^\d+(,\d+)*$/;
  return value.match(regExp);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="Text" id="Salary" maxlength="20" name="Salary" />
<label id="ErrorMessage"></label>
```

Comment: Thanks  it works how can i also allow only numeric values according to your regExp

Comment: If you want only numbers without commas, it's just `/^\d+$/`

Comment: just numbers with comma

Comment: also allows text characters ('s','a' ) i also disable entering 's','a'  thanks

Comment: It doesn't allow text characters. Try my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

change the regex to 
      var regExp = "^\d+(\,\d+)*$";
It works for any number of comma separated numbers